# CardDAV with osX/iPhone clients

Tags: iphone, macos, webdav

I am implementing a CardDAV backend to a crm package.

During the handshake with my backend the following request/response is handled:

```
PROPFIND /directory/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.202:9292
User-Agent: Address%20Book/883 CFNetwork/454.11.12 Darwin/10.7.0 (i386) (MacBookPro4%2C1)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Depth: 0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 147
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D:propfind xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:C="DAV:">
<D:prop>
<C:current-user-privilege-set/>
</D:prop>
</D:propfind>
HTTP/1.1 207
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 432
Connection: keep-alive
Server: thin 1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:">
  <D:response>
    <D:href>http://10.0.0.202:9292/directory/</D:href>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:current-user-privilege-set>
          <D:privilege>
            <D:read/>
          </D:privilege>
        </D:current-user-privilege-set>
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
    </D:propstat>
  </D:response>
</D:multistatus>
PROPFIND /contacts/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.202:9292
User-Agent: Address%20Book/883 CFNetwork/454.11.12 Darwin/10.7.0 (i386) (MacBookPro4%2C1)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Depth: 0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 167
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D:propfind xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav">
<D:prop>
<C:addressbook-home-set/>
</D:prop>
</D:propfind>
HTTP/1.1 207
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 408
Connection: keep-alive
Server: thin 1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:">
  <D:response>
    <D:href>http://10.0.0.202:9292/contacts/</D:href>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:addressbook-home-set>
          <D:href>http://10.0.0.202:9292/contacts/</D:href>
        </D:addressbook-home-set>
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
    </D:propstat>
  </D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```

This is despite my CardDAV backend never hinting that `/directory/` is anything that the client need concern itself with.

The client is returning the error `The CardDAV server returned an error (207) for the user "richo"`, however when I patched the server to return a different status code (200) I got the same error, but with a new status code.

I am working on the hunch that something else is upsetting it about the response. I have tried returning absolute instead of relative URL's (and vice versa) to no avail.

Any input appreciated. There is a similar issue on the mac forums [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2146094) that seems to end with resolution but the links are broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, it was a namespace issue.

using the `urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav` namespace where appropriate cleared it up.